# Require winforms app to shutdown before uninstall

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-installer, uninstallation

The answer probably involves a custom uninstall action, but it seems like such a major oversite and something that every application would want, so I thought I'd see if there is something easy I am missing.

I have a couple of projects create in Visual Studio 2008 using C#, Winform projects.  One uses click-once install, and one use a setup project.  They both allow you to leave the application running when you uninstall.  On Windows 7 you do get a warning, but have the option to leave it running anyway... on XP not even a warning.

Call me crazy, but the thought of all of my program files being removed, and my app still left running, doesn't sound like a good design at all.  Memories of GPFs come to mind, or the way .NET uses delay loading for DLLs, also could be a problem when the DLL needs to be loaded, and is gone.

**So is there an easy way to not allow uninstall if your app is still running?**

I'm using C# but I'm using the VB.NET Single Instance class to make sure my app only runs once, so maybe something that takes advantage of that as opposed to creating a mutex to check for?

Also my app only allows "per user" installs, not "all users", so I shouldn't have to worry about my app running in another session (if it is, it is OK to stay running because it should be 100% its own copy).

**Edit:** Since I'm not finding anything else, I've tried the mutex idea and it isn't working.  Here is my code:

In the app I have this to create the named mutex and keep alive while app running:

```
        System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "SafeShare");

        SingleInstanceApplication.Run(TabForm, NewInstanceHandler);

        GC.KeepAlive(m);
```

In the uninstall action I have this to loop until they exit (since it doesn't appear to be easy to provide a cancel option):

```
            while (true)
            {
                bool createdNew;
                System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "SafeShare", out createdNew);
                m.ReleaseMutex();
                if (createdNew)
                    break;
                MessageBox.Show(null,"Close XXX and click OK to continue uninstall.","Uninstall");
            }
```

createdNew is never set in the uninstall action, almost like it is running under a different session or something.  I haven't tried adding Global\ to the mutex name, but that would not work well for my app anyway because I do per-user installs, so one install should be able to keep running on another session even if one is uninstalled.

Comment: Not familiar with which API you'll need - either User32.dll, or kernel32.dll ?? - but you would query for a process id, or name equal  `xxx`.

Comment: Feature, not a bug, any locked files are deleted on the next reboot.  If you don't want to take advantage of that (why?  What "GPFs"?) then you'll need a custom uninstall action.  Which first requires reliably detecting that the program is still running.  Yes, a named mutex can do that.

Comment: GPF = General Page Fault, happens when Windows internals needs to load a resource or something from an EXE/DLL and it is missing.  Mostly happens when running an EXE over a network and you lose the network connection, but as far as I know it can happen anytime the file handle is invalidated or file is missing.

Comment: I'm trying the mutex idea, I'll update my question because even that seems to have issues.  Also, another reason I want my app closed is because it will recreate the user.config file sometimes, and I want everything gone after uninstall for security reasons also (and I'm sure the user would like this as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is there is no easy way to do this because it isn't something Microsoft wants you to do.

My answer did end up using a mutex, once I got the code correct it seems to work fine.

In the app I do:

```
System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "MyMutexNameHere");
SingleInstanceApplication.Run(TabForm, NewInstanceHandler);
GC.KeepAlive(m);
```

The SingleInstanceApplication.Run line is what runs your app, I'm using the VB.NET framework.

In the custom uninstall action I do:

```
while (true)
{
   bool createdNew;
   System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "MyMutexNameHere", out createdNew);
   m.Close();
   if (createdNew)
      break;
   MessageBox.Show(null,"Close XXX and click OK to continue uninstall.","Uninstall");
}
```

At first I was using m.ReleaseMutex() instead of m.Close() which I found out was throwing an exception because I didn't own the mutex.  Close was what I should have been using, just to make sure my copy was closed before I checked again (otherwise createNew was never true, if it wasn't true the first time).